# Edit table row javascript with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have a table, that is dynamically increased with Firebase, and I need an edit button on each row of the table. I am having trouble with the edit button, how I can update data based on the id of each user and save this update then display table with the update.

```
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Password </th>
                <th>edit</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tablel">
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Javascript

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("Puser");

ref.on('value',function(snapshot){


 var content ='';
snapshot.forEach(function(data){

  var val = data.val();
  content += '<tr>';
  content += '<td>' + val.email +'</td>';
  content += '<td>' + val.email +'</td>';               
  content += '<td><button  onclick="Update_State()"> edit</button></td>';
  content += '<td><button  > save </button></td>';
  content += '</tr>';
});
$('#tablel').append(content);

})

function Update_State(){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a multi-step process:

1. Add the key of the item to each row that you generate.
2. Use that key when the user clicks the button to update the correct node.

The first step requires a change to your existing content generation script:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("Puser");

ref.on('value',function(snapshot){
  var content ='';
  snapshot.forEach(function(data){
    var key = data.key;
    var val = data.val();
    content += `<tr id="'+key+'">`;
    content += '<td>' + val.email +'</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.email +'</td>';               
    content += '<td><button  onclick="Update_State(\''+key+'\')"> edit</button></td>';
    content += '<td><button  > save </button></td>';
    content += '</tr>';
  });
  $('#tablel').append(content);
})
```

As you may see, I  made a few more changes to your code:

1. Indent each level properly, which helps enormously in making your code readable. This alone makes it more likely that you spot problems in it, and also makes it more likely that someone here may help.
2. Get the key of each child node, and then add that to the row, and also to the `onclick` hander. Only one or the other is needed, but I felt more comfortable doing both. ¯_(ツ)_/¯
3. Use `` instead of `append`, as otherwise you keep adding more and more rows as someone makes a change to one of the rows.

Now with that out of the way, you can use the key in the `Update_State` function to call the database on the correct child node:

```
function Update_State(key){
  console.log(key);
  var ref = firebase.database().ref("Puser");
  ref.child(key).update({ property: "value" });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how I can make one cell editable if click the edit button. I want to make this table inline editable table but I am a beginner with firebase and javascript

Comment: I wrote a pretty decent tutorial above, honestly already quite a bit more than is reasonable in a Stack Overflow answer. If this is not enough for you to get started, then your question is too broad for Stack Overflow. In that case I recommend you follow a few tutorials about web development, and about Firebase, before attempting what you currently are trying.